# Messaging in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, messaging

I'm using the http://www.novawave.net/public/rails_messaging_tutorial.html tutorial to implement messaging on my ruby on rails project.  I am running ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3 and keep getting this error

```
NoMethodError in SentController#create  
undefined method 'each_line' for ["35"]:Array
```

Application Trace:

```
app/models/message.rb:13:in 'prepare_copies'  
app/controllers/sent_controller.rb:24:in 'create'
```

Message model:

```
1   class Message < ActiveRecord::Base  
2     belongs_to :author, :class_name => "User"  
3     has_many :message_copies  
4     has_many :recipients, :through => :message_copies  
5     before_create :prepare_copies  
6    
7     attr_accessor :to #array of people to send to  
8     attr_accessible :subject, :body, :to  
9  
10    def prepare_copies  
11      return if to.blank?  
12    
13      to.each_line do |recipient|  
14        recipient = User.find(recipient)  
15        message_copies.build(:recipient_id => recipient.id, :folder_id => recipient.inbox.id)  
16      end  
17    end  
18  end
```

Sent controller:

```
class SentController < ApplicationController  
  ...  

  def create  
    current_user = User.find(session[:user_id])  
    @message = current_user.sent_messages.build(params[:message])  

    if @message.save  
      flash[:notice] = "Message sent."  
      redirect_to :action => "index"  
    else  
      render :action => "new"  
    end  
  end  
end
```

If I edit and use:

```
to.each do |recipient|  
  ...  
end
```

I get a different error:

```
RuntimeError in SentController#create  
Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted the id of nil, use object_id
```

Application Trace:

```
app/models/message.rb:15:in 'block in prepare_copies'  
app/models/message.rb:13:in 'each'  
app/models/message.rb:13:in 'prepare_copies'  
app/controllers/sent_controller.rb:24:in 'create'
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to call each on an Array is with your second example:

```
to.each do |recipient|  
  ...  
end
```

As for the error message you receive, it appears that no `User`s exists for the given `to`s that you're looping over (`User.find()` returns nothing). The stack trace is complaining that you're calling the accessor `id()` on a nil object given this line:

`:recipient_id => recipient.id`

Create a mock `User` and send a message to only that User to verify that this is the cause of your error. If it is you'll need some error handling to ensure that you don't call `id()` and `inbox()` on nil records.

Another possibility is that you have an `inbox` that is nil, in which case you'll call `id()` again on a nil object.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  So I checked and the User is being set properly, however it's throwing the nil on the folder (recipient.inbox.id).  So I tried creating a new user and now I'm throwing an error on folder.build

User model:
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    has_many :folders
    ...
    before_create :build_inbox
    
    def build_inbox
      folders = Folder.build(:name => "Inbox")
    end

Folder model:
  class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base
    acts_as_tree
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :messages, :class_name => "MessageCopy"
  end

Folder schema from sqlite3:
  CR

Comment: I did and now I'm getting a NoMethodError in UsersController#create
undefined method `build' for #<Class:0x0000010452a558> which is being thrown when folders = Folder.build(:name => "Inbox" is being called.

Comment: It sounds like you're not extending `ActiveRecord` in `Folder`. Make sure Folder is defined as `class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base`

Comment: it does... 'class Folder < ActiveRecord::Base  
  acts_as_tree  
  belongs_to :user  
  has_many :messages, :class_name => "MessageCopy"  
end'

Answer (score 0):

The proper code snippet at the site you have mentioned is:

```
def prepare_copies
  return if to.blank?

  to.each do |recipient|
    recipient = User.find(recipient)
    message_copies.build(:recipient_id => recipient.id, :folder_id => recipient.inbox.id)
  end
end
```

This is the 8th black frame.

Answer (score 0):

I used a plugin to create a messaging system on my app days ago and it worked pretty well, with full support to Rails 3. If you still with problems, try [it out](https://github.com/professionalnerd/simple-private-messages).